# Cubic's derivative

Tags: calculus, polynomials, quadratics, cubics

For a cubic $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$, the radicand of the derivative is $b^2-3ac$ and I was wondering if there's a word for this term. I know that the nature of it being positive, zero, or negative will affect how many critical points the cubic has... but is there a name for this?

Also, based on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2375118/612996), there are only 6 possibilities? For each positive or negative $a$ value, then there are three possibilities for the "discriminant" (of the derivative)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may say (an equation for) stationary points or [crtical points](https://www.math24.net/critical-points).

[image]

The [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) for a cubic is

$$-27 a^2 d^2 + 18 a b c d - 4 a c^3 - 4 b^3 d + b^2 c^2$$

For $n$-th order polynomial equation,

$$\Delta=a^{2n-2} \prod_{i<j} (\alpha_i-\alpha_j)^2=(-1)^{n(n-1)/2}a^{2n-2} \prod_{i \ne j} (\alpha_i-\alpha_j)$$ where
$\displaystyle f(x)=a\prod_{i=1}^n (x-\alpha_i)$.

**Further points to be noticed**

- Note that for a polynomial equation beyond linear, there exists at least one global extremum or one inflection point.
- $\displaystyle \frac{\sqrt{b^2-3ac}}{3a} \in \mathbb{C}$ in general, relates to linear eccentricity of Steiner in-ellipse of the roots.
- Please refer to my post  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1603162/geometric-meaning-of-complex-cubic-polynomial-coefficients/2763171#2763171).

Answer (score 0):

The quantity $b^2-3ac$ does not tell the number of real roots, and I don't think it has a name.

The discriminant of a cubic, which does tell that number ($1,2$ or $3$) is

$$18abcd-4b^3d+b^2c^2-4ac^3-27a^2c2.$$

Comment: The last term is $-27a^2d^2$?